# db2 Stored Procedure Merge Error

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will run a merge from a staging table to the master table, however, I am getting this error when I try to create:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;.LAST_CHANGED_DATE
);<psm_semicolon>, DRIVER=3.69.24 [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=-104]
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateM25
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
MERGE INTO MEDILOAD.M25 M25
USING ( SELECT NDC_UPC_HR1,
        ID_NUM_FORMAT,
        REC_CODE,
        TRAN_CODE,
        OVERLOADED_AREA,
        LAST_CHANGED_DATE
        FROM MEDILOAD.M25_STAGE) M25_STAGE
on (M25.NDC_UPC_HR1 = M25_STAGE.NDC_UPC_HR1 and M25.REC_CODE = M25_STAGE.REC_CODE)
WHEN matched then
update set
M25.NDC_UPC_HR1 = M25_STAGE.NDC_UPC_HR1,
M25.ID_NUM_FORMAT = M25_STAGE.ID_NUM_FORMAT,
M25.REC_CODE = M25_STAGE.REC_CODE,
M25.TRAN_CODE = M25_STAGE.TRAN_CODE,
M25.OVERLOADED_AREA = M25_STAGE.OVERLOADED_AREA,
M25.LAST_CHANGED_DATE = M25_STAGE.LAST_CHANGED_DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED then
INSERT
(
M25.NDC_UPC_HR1,
M25.ID_NUM_FORMAT,
M25.REC_CODE,
M25.TRAN_CODE,
M25.OVERLOADED_AREA,
M25.LAST_CHANGED_DATE
)
VALUES
(
M25_STAGE.NDC_UPC_HR1,
M25_STAGE.ID_NUM_FORMAT,
M25_STAGE.REC_CODE,
M25_STAGE.TRAN_CODE,
M25_STAGE.OVERLOADED_AREA,
M25_STAGE.LAST_CHANGED_DATE
);
END
@
```

Comment: How do you execute that statement? There is a problem with the statement terminator.

Comment: I haven't even been able to create the stored procedure to execute.  I use SQL Workbench/J to do my creation and then I will execute the SP from SSIS.

Comment: What is the statement terminator you have set in your SQL Workbench? In your CREATE PROC you are using "@".

Comment: I don't see where i can define my statement delimiter.